# What's the procedure to change password for default cassandra user?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a 5 node cassandra cluster with RF=3 (only for application related db) with only 1 data centre. I wish to change password of default **cassandra** user

My system_auth key space has the following setting

```
CREATE KEYSPACE system_auth WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'}  AND durable_writes = true;
```

Questions

1. Should the strategy by changed to NetworkTopology ? I thought it
   wasn't required as there is only 1 DC
2. Should the RF be 3 same as for other application related DB ?
3. When I change the credentials of default cassandra user using ALTER
   USER command, should I change it in each of the hosts since currently RF=1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should the strategy by changed to NetworkTopology ? I thought it
>   wasn't required as there is only 1 DC

Since its a single data center, simple strategy should work fine. Consider changing to Network Topology strategy when going Multi-DC

> Should the RF be 3 same as for other application related DB ?

Its definitely recommended to have system_auth keyspace RF to be more than 1. Having RF=1 entails only one copy of the storing user credentials and hence any particular node loss would cause loss of a portion of authorization data. Increase it to a minimum of 3.

> When I change the credentials of default cassandra user using ALTER USER command, should I change it in each of the hosts since currently RF=1 ?

No its not required to change in each node. With RF=1, the user credentials of "Cassandra" would live in only node. Irrespective of which node you pick to change its password, it will act as a coordinator and route the password change to appropriate node storing Cassandra user. Again if you loose that node which stored Cassandra, you potentially lost access to the cluster. So having RF=3, will avoid that.